# Work Around for drag and drop in playwright python

Tags: playwright-python

I am trying to implement a drag and drop functionality(I was able to see there is an open issue regarding this) with the currently available mouse actions but so far not able to do that. so i am looking for a work around for that, is there anyway we can implement drag and drop in playwright python. below is the code that i am trying to use.

```
await page.mouse.move(472, 399)
await page.mouse.down()
await page.mouse.move(991, 313)
await page.mouse.up()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume in your case the HTML5 drag and drop is not working.

Unfortunately at the time of writing this the current playwright python (1.10.x) won't trigger `dragstart` and `drop` events through the `mouse.down`, `mouse.move` and `mouse.up` API.

The following code however should work (using sync_api),

```
# This element should have the draggable attribute value as true
src_elem = page.query_selector('div.foo')
# This element should be the element as the drop target
dest_elem = page.query_selector('div.bar')
# Create a data transfer JSHandle instance
data_transfer = page.evaluate_handle('() => new DataTransfer()')
src_elem.dispatch_event('dragstart', { 'dataTransfer': data_transfer })
dest_elem.dispatch_event('drop', { 'dataTransfer': data_transfer })
# Now check whether the dropped effect is achieved
dest_elem.wait_for_selector('ENTER SELECTOR AFTER DROP EFFECT')
```